# On a variant of Eidelheit's theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

A theorem of Eidelheit from 1940's asserts that two Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic if and only if $L(X)$ and $L(Y)$, the algebras of all bounded linear operators, are isomorphic as Banach algebras. Can one relax this to prove that if $L(X)$ is isomorphic to a subalgebra of $L(Y)$ then $X$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $Y$?

Comment: I have a feeling the answer should be negative but I don't recall if there is a known counter-example

Comment: Perhaps it would be instructive for you to work through the proof of Eidelheit's theorem, attempt to prove the version you state in your post, and see what goes wrong? As it stands, your question does not indicate what you have tried/read in order to solve this problem

Comment: Depending on the proof (there are many of them), one usually uses surjectivity of the isomorphism from $L(X)$ to $L(Y)$ to conclude boundedness of a linear isomorphism $X\to Y$ being constructed.

Comment: The other place where surjectivity is essential is when you want to argue that the image of a rank-one operator is rank-one. This is not true without this assumption: think of the infinite ampliation of operators on $\ell_2$.

Comment: Why do you expect such a result? I mean, it doesn't even look natural, as the natural homomorphism is in the opposite direction.